# pys60 thread not working in symbian python

Tags: python, multithreading, messaging, pys60

I am developing a sms app for symbian using pys60.
I have created a thread for sending the sms but theread is not working.
I want this thread to run in background, irrespective of applicaton closed or not.
contact index is a dictionary with contact nos and names.

```
def send_sms(contact_index):
    import thread
    appuifw.note(u"entered to send sms thread")
    tid = thread.start_new_thread(send_sms_thread, (contact_index, ))
    appuifw.note(u"completed")
```

it enters "entered to send sms thread" but doesnt go after that.
the function sens_sms_thread is :

```
def send_sms_thread(contact_index):
    appuifw.note(u"entering the thread in sending sms in loops")
    for numbers in contact_index:
        name = contact_index[number]
        appuifw.note(u"sending sms to %s ." % name)
        messaging.sms_send(numbers, message_content, '7bit', cb, '')
        e32.ao_sleep(30)
```

can anyone tell me why it is not entering into this thread which will run in background inrrespective of application closed or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/threading.html) module. [`Thread`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/threading.html#thread-objects)s created by this module will be waited on by the main thread before the process exits.

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=send_sms_thread, args=(contact_index,))
thread.start()
```

Threads created elsewhere, or with the [`daemon`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) attribute are not waited for.

Comment: I tried threading.therad but it waits. I dont want it to wait till sms sending finishes. i want this send_sms_thread function should run in background even if i closed the application.

Comment: @sam: Then you need to create a new process, likely a daemon process.

Comment: yes. thanks for replies.i dont have idea about creating the same. can you kindly let me know if u know it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next snippet:

```
if __name__=='__main__':

    th = e32.ao_callgate(Udp_recv)
    thread.start_new_thread(th,())

    for i in range(10):
        tmp = (str(i)+data)[0:10]
```

`Udp_recv` is the function running in background.